# MongoEngine query to get Post's author and Comments authors for Posts (at the same time)

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm working on a web project with **Django and MongoDB** as my database (using MongoEngine to connect them). 
I have to create Celery task to cleanup old user accounts. I need to only clean lazy users accounts without any content after one month (lazy users are automatically created users when they first connect to the website). What count as content? Any posts from the user or comments on any of the posts.

I did it like this, but I want to transform this into query if possible:

```
def clean_inactive_lazy_users():
    users_with_content = []

    for post in api_models.Post.objects:
        users_with_content.append(post.author)
        for comment in post.comments:
            users_with_content.append(comment.author)

    users_with_content = list(set(users_with_content))

    for user in account_models.User.objects:
        if not user.is_authenticated() and (timezone.now() - user.connection_last_unsubscribe).days >= settings.DELETE_LAZY_USER_AFTER_DAYS and user not in users_with_content:
            user.delete()
```

The models look like this:

base.py

```
class AuthoredEmbeddedDocument(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    author = mongoengine.ReferenceField(models.User, required=True)

class AuthoredDocument(mongoengine.Document):
    author = mongoengine.ReferenceField(models.User, required=True)
```

api_models:

```
from . import base

class Comment(base.AuthoredEmbeddedDocument):
    """
    This class defines document type for comments on posts.
    """

class Post(base.AuthoredDocument):
    """
    This class defines document type for posts.
    """
```

account_models:

```
class User(auth.User):
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.has_usable_password()
```

Hopefully I provided enough information so you can help me with the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple ways for you to clean this up.

You could get all author unique ids of posts with something like:

```
user_ids_with_posts_list = Posts.objects.scalar('author.id', flat=True).distinct('author.id')
```

[scalar](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.scalar) should give you a list of author ids instead of document objects and [distinct](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.distin) 
 should make sure they are unique.  This pushes what you are doing in python to mongodb

You could then construct a query for Users.  You would hvae to change your days ago into a date.  What condition is `has_usable_password` checking for?

```
start_time = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=DAYS_AGO_CONSTANT)

invalid_users = User.objects.filter(connection_last_unsubscribe__lte=start_time,
                                     password__isnull=True).exclude(pk__in=user_ids_with_posts_list)
invalid_users.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got some new ideas from it. The only thing I still can't figure out is how to combine your first query over posts with one over comments - if this is even possible.
`has_usable_password` calls `hashers.is_password_usable(self.password)`, where hashers is: `from django.contrib.auth import hashers`

Comment: I will try this when I get home. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dm03514: But mongoengine is not Django ORM. And MongoDB is not relational database. There is nothing like subquery there.